# StringToByteArray() throw exception in C# 2.0

Tags: c#, c#-2.0, arrays

I am practicing StringToByteArray() on VS2005. But throw exception. Could you please tell me more information about it?

Exception alert **An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Could not find any recognizable digits.**

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
    {
        int NumberChars = hex.Length;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
            // exception here
            bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return bytes;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
            byte[] myByte = new byte[2];
        myByte = StringToByteArray("0x0");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either need to drop the "0x" from the start of the string you pass in, or start your `for` loop with `int i = 2;`.  Also you're allocating the array in your method.  You don't need to do it `Main` as well.

Comment: He's also not making sure the string consists of an even number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have the possibility of a divide by zero exception...

After you fix that, you need to continue your input validation by ensuringing that your string starts with 0x and then skip the prefix when you do your conversion.